# “Searches revealed that” vs. “Searches revealed”

Tags: that-it

I would like to know whether the word *that* can be removed in the following sentence:

> Searches revealed **that** Johns was awarded a grant by the Chilean Innovation Program.

I read in other threads that *that* can be omitted in sentences like “She said they won’t come.” But is this the case with the above structure?

Is it correct to say:

> Searches revealed Johns was awarded. . . .

Answer (score 1):

The conjunction *that* has a function. Sometimes it's redundant because when the *that* is missing, the meaning of sentence is still instantly clear. Therefore, the *that* is often optional.

Some people see the word "optional" and apply it dogmatically: that's the norm for most language users and rule followers.

Careful writers think about each instance and decide based on whether the sentence works better with or without the *that*.

In the sentence that you ask about, my feeling is that it reads better and is clearer with the *that* than without it, but that's just one man's opinion. I prefer to use the conjunction, but perhaps that's because I studied French, which has an equivalent structure that's almost always (I'm not sure whether it isn't dispensable in some cases) required. Other native English-speakers will have different opinions.

Both versions of the sentence are grammatical and acceptable and clear.